# RegEx: Match any non-empty string, including line breaks

Tags: regex

I'd like to **match any non-empty, multi-line string** fully. In PHP-Flavour I'd do it with the `\X` token, which matches any characters including line breaks. Unfortunately, I need to use Java, where the `\X` token does not work.

Example of a string I would like to match fully (Match 1):

```
This is a 
multi-line
string with some charakters like $ and / and ´
to match fully.
```

Comment: Why do you think the `\W` does not work in Java? You can double escape it `\\W` If the string should not be empty `^\h*\S.*` https://regex101.com/r/KEKBOs/1 If you want to match multiple non empty strings `^\h*\S.*(?:\R\h*\S.*)*` https://regex101.com/r/11exFU/1

Comment: `\W` works perfectly in Java regex. And to match any string you use `.`, not `\W`. `(?s)\A.+\z` matches any non-empty string fully. In Java, `.matches("(?s).+")`

Comment: Okay, `(?s)\A.+\z` seems to work, altough i don't understand why.

Comment: Regex101 helped me to understand that the s modifier can be used to make `.` match newline. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Yes, and `\A` matches a start of string position and `\z` matches the very end of string.

Comment: Wiktor, Would you like to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java regex flavor, `\X` is really not supported, and any code point pattern can be expressed with "any non-diacritic char + any zero or more diacritics", i.e. `\P{M}\p{M}*+`.

However, you just want to match any non-empty string. You can use

```
(?s)\A.+\z
```

pattern. *Details*:

- `(?s)` - an embedded flag option (equal to `Pattern.DOTALL` in Java) that makes `.` match any chars including line break chars
- `\A` - string start anchor
- `.+` - any *one* or more chars, as many as possible (it is a greedy dot pattern)
- `\z` - the very end of string.

To match *any non-empty and non-blank string*, you'd use

```java
(?s)\A\s*\S.*\z
```

The `\s*\S.*` part matches zero or more whitespaces (`\s*`), then any non-whitespace char (`\S`) and then `.*` matches the rest of the string.